# JQuery script failed running on IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I just wrote some JQuery script to practice accessing JSON data and it ran perfectly on Firefox, Chrome and IE 11. However, it failed running on IE 8 with following error message:

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 2
Char: 29489
Code: 0
URI: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js


Message: '$' is undefined
Line: 12
Char: 4
Code: 0
```

Is it because JQuery 2.x stops supporting IE 8? According to http://jquery.com/browser-support/, or other causes? I cannot figure it out.

Anyone got any hints? Thanks in advance.

The code is below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div1">dv1</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getData(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"j.json",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(jsondata){
                output(jsondata);               
            }
        });
    }

    function output(json){

        //var Data = eval('(' + json + ')');
        var html = '';
        //alert(Data.length);
        for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
            html += ' name:' + json[i].name + ' age:' + json[i].age;
        }

        document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = html;

    }

    setInterval(getData, 3000);

    </script>             
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery 2.0 does not support IE8 or earlier.  You must use some 1.x version of jQuery.